# Routes add undefined param in url?

Tags: angular

I have this two path:

```
{ path: "evidencija/:type/:specId/:activeIndex", component: VpnEvidencijaFlowComponent },
  { path: "evidencija/:type/:offerId/:specId/:activeIndex", component: VpnEvidencijaFlowComponent },
```

In ts i have this:

```
 this.router.navigate(['/evidencija', this.type, children.key, 0], {queryParams: this.queries});
```

Problem is that i get all of this params but it set undefined on place where should be offerId but i dont have it in some cases. Any suggestion why do i get undefined in url ?

Comment: Please give a [mcve], you're referring to multiple properties without actually showing their values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your route, you don't have to define param in you path.

he must just associate a name with a route (and therefore a page)

If you want pass param in you route, you need to use navigate like this :

```
 this.router.navigate(['/evidencija', this.type, children.key, 0]);
```

and you path is just :

```
 { path: 'evidencija', component: VpnEvidencijaFlowComponent},
```

And for read your param in the other component import :

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

Declare it in contructor :

```
private route: ActivatedRoute
```

And get your param in NgInit :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = params['id'];
    });
  }
```